# Run background task continuously in .net core "static class" vs "BackgroundService" whats the difference

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a.net core api application (.net 6). My application must run a query to database to get and update my internal cache with the most used data to avoid hit the database unnecessary.
This task update cache every 30 seconds.
BUT, I normally use a simple static class with a timer and a "Initialize()" method to initialize timer and start timer. This Initialize() method is called when application start and timer keep running until application stop. This works perfectly but wherever I read, I found that always the suggested workaround for this case is to use a BackgroundService to host the timer instead of a simple static class. What are the differences and why I should use BackgroundService?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary everywhere but here MS uses backgroundservice to execute a timer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 3):

1. Static class is not testable
2. You can't use DI to inject dependencies into a static class
3. The host is not aware of the work done by the static class and hence will just shutdown without giving you the ability to finish the work gracefully.

The third point is the most important and graceful shutdown of `BackgrondServices` is supported by the host.

Comment: In the point 3 you can do....
Program.css....

app.Lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnStart);
app.Lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnStop);

void OnStart()
{
   MyStaticClass.Initialize();

}

void OnStop()
{
       MyStaticClass.Terminate();
}

Comment: @AnibalDavidAcosta Yes, you can, Once you are aware of the problem there is always a solution. But in `BackgroundService` this is built-in functionality.